# How to make a file transfer program in python

Tags: python

The title might not be relevant for my question becuase I don't actually want a wireless file transfering script, I need a file manager type.

I want something with which I can connect my phone with my pc (eg: hotspot and wifi) and then I would like to show text file browser (I have the code for that) by sending lists of all files and folders using `os.listdir()`, whenever the selected option is a file (`os.path.isdir() == False`), I would like to transfer the file and run it(like: picture, video, etc).

The file Browser code which I wrote runs on windows and also Android (after making a few changes) using `qpython`.

My code is

```
import os
def FileBrowser(cwd = os.getcwd()):
  while True:
    if cwd[-1:] != "\\":
      cwd = cwd + "\\"
    files = os.listdir(cwd)
    count = 1
    tmpp = ""
    print("\n\n" + "_"*50 +"\n\n")
    print(cwd + "\n")
    for f in files:
      if os.path.isdir(cwd + f) == True:
        s1 = str(count) + ". " + f
        tmps1 = 40 - (len(s1)+5)
        t2 = int(tmps1/3)
        s1 = s1 + " " * t2 + "-" * (tmps1 - t2)
        print(s1 + "<dir>")
      else:
        print(str(count) + ". " + f + tmpp)
      count = count + 1
    s = raw_input("Enter the file/Directory: ")
    if s == "...":
      tmp1 = cwd.count("\\")
      tmp2 = cwd.rfind("\\")
      if tmp1 > 1:
        cwd = cwd[0:tmp2]
        tmp2 = cwd.rfind("\\")
        cwd = cwd[0:tmp2+1]
        continue
      else:
        continue
    else:
      s = int(s) - 1
    if os.path.isdir(cwd + files[s]) == True:
      cwd = cwd + files[s] + "\\"
      continue
    else:
      f1 = files[s]
      break
  return f1
def main():
  fb = FileBrowser()
main()
```

Comment: My question is, how do I send data between my pc and phone wirelessly using python?

Comment: Probably look into sockets https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html

Answer (score 3):

A very naive approach using Python is to go to the root of the directory you want to be served and use:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

The connect to it on port 8000.

Answer (score 3):

you may need to [socket programming](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sockets.html). creating a link (connection) between your PC and you smart phone and then try to transfer files

Comment: I am very confused, what are sockets? does it mean using internet? If not, what is it? I am only aware of two types of file transfers without internet bluetooth and wifi. Is socket similar to wifi?

Comment: socket is an I/O library which allows you to send your data over networks. it uses network protocols such as TCP/UDP and etc to connect multi-machine to each other and make them able to transmit their data for each other. and about infrastructure you may use wifi or wired-base media to connect them together. doesn't matter what kind of network you have. but in which case wifi the the best choice